# How to get row number of a cell with a specific text in Google Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In my column N, there is only one cell with text - "Double-Clic:
How to get the row number of that cell.

A part of my code has errors:

```
function AddNewRows() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
  var a = spreadsheet.getRange("N1:N" + spreadsheet.getLastRow()).createTextFinder("Double-Click").matchEntireCell(true).findNext().getRow()+1;
  var b = a+6
  ;

Edit 2:
Above issue is resolved. Thank you so much to all those who answered it.

But getting error in this last line = Range not found.

function AddNewRows() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
  var a = spreadsheet.getRange("N1:N" + spreadsheet.getLastRow()).createTextFinder("Double-Click").matchEntireCell(true).findNext().getRow()+1;
  var b = a+6
  spreadsheet.getRange(a,b).activate();
  spreadsheet.setCurrentCell(spreadsheet.getRange("A" & a &":A" & b));


Please help.
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Using Textfinder

**find first occurrence**

```
function FindRow() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const r = ss.createTextFinder("Double-Click").matchEntireCell(true).findNext();
  const location = r.getA1Notation();
  const sheet = r.getSheet();
  const row = r.getRow();
  Logger.log('%s!%s row:%s',sheet.getName(),location,row);
  return row;
}
```

[findNext() returns a range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder#findNext())

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think that the reason for your issue is due to `getRange` of `spreadsheet.getRange.createTextFinder`.

From `In my column N, there is only one cell with text - "Double-Clic: How to get the row number of that cell.`, when you want to search the value of `Double-Click` from the column "N", please modify as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function FindRow() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var a = sheet.getRange("N1:N" + sheet.getLastRow()).createTextFinder("Double-Click").matchEntireCell(true).findNext().getRow();
  return a
}
```

- When you want to search from the row 2, please modify `"N1:N" + sheet.getLastRow()` to `"N2:N" + sheet.getLastRow()`.

#### Note:

- `createTextFinder` method is also existing in Class Range, Class Sheet, Class Spreadsheet. For example, when you want to search the value from the sheet, you can also modify as follows.

  ```
    function FindRow() {
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      var a = sheet.createTextFinder("Double-Click").matchEntireCell(true).findNext().getRow();
      return a
    }
  ```

#### Reference:

- [createTextFinder(findText) of Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#createTextFinder(String))

### Added:

From `Above issue is resolved. Thank you so much to all those who answered it.`, I understood that your question was resolved.

About your new question of `But getting error in this last line = Range not found.`, when I saw your script of your new question, I think that when you want to add the string, `"A" & a &":A" & b` is required to be modified. It's `"A" + a + ":A" + b`.

But, when the value of `a` is different from the value of `b`, an error occurs. Because `setCurrentCell` can be used for one cell.

Unfortunately, I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your new question of `Also, can I add "+1" in the last as I want the next row which has the text "Double-Click"` in your comment,

If you want to activate the cells of `"A" + a + ":A" + b`, please modify as follows.

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
var a = spreadsheet.getRange("N1:N" + spreadsheet.getLastRow()).createTextFinder("Double-Click").matchEntireCell(true).findNext().getRow() + 1;
var b = a + 6;
spreadsheet.getRange("A" + a + ":A" + b).activate();
```

If you want to activate the cell of the next row of the search cell, please modify as follows.

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
spreadsheet.getRange("N1:N" + spreadsheet.getLastRow()).createTextFinder("Double-Click").matchEntireCell(true).findNext().offset(1, 0).activate();
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But, my code is showing more erorr. I have put in Edit 2. Please help

Comment: Also, can I add "+1" in the last as I want the next row which has the text "Double-Click"

Comment: @user18308583 About your 1st question, I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question, although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your new question, I added the script modified your showing script. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your new question, I apologize.